# Convert issues asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have following code but it shows conversion issues. please help me to solve. It shows cannot convert decimal to string.

```
    decimal finalrate;
    finalRate = decimal.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SECTION_OBC_PRICE"].ToString());
    TextBoxSectionUR.Text = (finalRate * 75) / 100);
```

Comment: "It shows conversion issues" doesn't tell us much - and we don't know the input values, which doesn't help either. We don't know where the problem is, or what the error message is...

Answer (score 1):

You could call the `.ToString()` method to convert the decimal to string:

```
TextBoxSectionUR.Text = ((finalRate * 75) / 100).ToString();
```